# Fastlane Automating 2FA with account Enterprise

Tags: ios, fastlane, fastlane-match

we have a CI Jenkins pipeline where Fastlane can connect to Apple Store using API_KEY generated from Apple Holder account avoiding 2FA authentication.
Now, we have a problem when we try to update provisiong profile (Fastlane - plugin MATCH) with the Enterprise account for in-house application. In fact, it's not possible generate (from ios DeveloperConsole) an API KEY for Enterprise Account.
How can we use Fastlane ("app_store_connect_api_key" or file .json) to avoid Apple 2FA for Apple Enterprise account?
We have tried to set the parameter in_house: true/false but not resolved
Thanks in advance

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible at this time; https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/discussions/18049

Comment: Thanks a lot Paul. You are right: I'm afraid it's not possibile